# How to add associated object to uitapgesture?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Currently I have in my code

```
tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(addCompoundToLabel:)];
```

My code would be cleaner if it was something like

```
tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(addCompoundToLabel:) withObject:data];
```

I read that associated objects allow you to pass objects in a gesture recognizer, but after reading the docs, I don't quite understand how to implement it into my code. An example implementation of associated objects would be appreciated. Thanks

EDIT:

this is what the beginning of  `addCompound` looks like

```
- (void)addCompoundToLabel:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

 if( [recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ) {

      FormulaLabel* label = (FormulaLabel*)[recognizer view];
```

Comment: why you want to do that? you can subclass UITapGestureRecognizer and add a ivar member

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using associated objects is a messy solution. Instead, you could create a false target object, give it your `UIView` and your `Data`, and have access to both of them in the selector method. It is a lot more readable, and your code expresses your intent a lot better.

Here is a quick and dirty example:

```
@interface FalseTarget : NSObject {
    MyViewController *_viewCtrl;
    MyData *_data;
}
-(id)initWithViewCtrl:(MyViewController*)viewCtrl andData:(MyData*)data;
-(void)tap:(id)sender;
@end

@implementation
-(id)initWithViewCtrl:(MyViewController*)viewCtrl andData:(MyData*)data {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _viewCtrl = viewCtrl;
        _data = data;
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)tap:(id)sender {
    [_viewCtrl processTapFromSender:sender withData:_data];
}
@end
```

Add `processTapFromSender:withData:` method to your controller:

```
-(void)processTapFromSender:(id)sender withData:(MyData*)data {
    // Your action
}
```

Now you can create your tap recognizer like this:

```
FalseTarget *target = [[FalseTarget alloc] initWithViewCtrl:self andData:data];
tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:target action:@selector(tap:)];
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this so that the `tap` method is in the view controller?